# HTML Form to XML and LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm doing a simple html form and I'd like to be able to save the output that I type in onto the Local Storage of my website.
Is there any way of converting the inputs from a HTML Form using raw Javascript or PHP onto an internal XML on the Local Storage in my browser?

Comment: `localStorage` is not stored on the server.  It is a storage medium of the browser on each user's machine.  Are you aware of this?

Comment: @Taplar Yes, I've already edited. I want to store the output of a html form in my web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just want to be able to save data in the form and recover it from localStorage when you need to.

You're going to want to use JavaScript and go through your form inputs and then save them respectively to the `localStorage` object.

For example if I had an element:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
```

I could save the content to the `localStorage` object by doing

```
localStorage.setItem("fname", document.getElementById("fname").value);
```

I could then retrieve the content and put it back in by doing

```
document.getElementById("fname").value = localStorage.getItem("fname");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Much appreciated! I was losing my head thinking of how this could be made.  The thing is that i want to "create an xml " containing the form inputs. I've looked and it seems I need to use Javascript to create an xml document and then add, step by step, the form inputs.

Comment: @Learner33 Of course :)! If this is what you're looking for, just mark my answer as the solution so others know that this question is solved already. Goodluck!